# Реализация layout`ов для библиотеки для создания текстовых интерфейсов (TUI) - C#

Tags: c#, консоль, ui

Здравствуйте! В данный момент я пытаюсь написать маленькую библиотеку для создания текстовых интерфейсов. В планах - основные элементы управления (кнопки, чекбоксы, радикнопки, выпадающие меню, слайдеры, и т.д), способы привязки событий (что-то очень простое, а-ля bind в tkinter) и, собственно, способы их размещения - те самые layout`ы.

В данный момент, все виджеты наследуют от базового класса - 
**Widget.cs**

```
    using System;

    namespace widgets
    {
        public abstract class Widget
        {
            public int X;

            public int Y;

            public int Width;

            public int Height;

            public delegate void callback(); // очень криво сделал, подскажите, как будет правильнее

            public event callback OnClick;

            public void Click()
            {
                OnClick ();
            }

            abstract public void Paint();

            abstract public void PaintSelected();

            abstract public void KeyPressed(ConsoleKey key);
        }
    }
```

Все layout`ы также наследуют от базового класса
**Layout.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace widgets
    {
        public abstract class Layout
        {
            public int X;

            public int Y;

            public int Width;

            public int Height;

            public List<Widget> Widgets{get; protected set;}

            public abstract void Aline();

            public void AddWidget(Widget w)
            {
                Widgets.Add(w);
            }

            public void AddLayout(Layout l)
            {
                l.Aline();

                foreach(Widget i in l.Widgets)
                    AddWidget(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Далее, есть два класса **VLayout** и **HLayout** (устроены они, понятное дело, аналогично друг другу)

**VLayout.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace widgets
    {
        public class VLayout : Layout
        {
            public VLayout()
            {
                Widgets = new List<Widget>();
            }

            public override void Aline() // вероятно, ошибка в том, что все виджеты выравниваются  одинаково.  
// необходимо их как-то различать, но как - не представляю
            {
                int height = Height-1;
                int heach = height / Widgets.Count;

                for(int i=0; i<Widgets.Count; i++)
                {
                    Widgets[i].Y = (heach+1)*i;
                    Widgets[i].X = X;

                    Widgets[i].Height = heach;
                    Widgets[i].Width = Width;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

При попытке использования всего этого вместе (см.код ниже), получается, как на картинке

```
    HLayout l = new HLayout();
    VLayout l1 = new VLayout();

    // a, b, c, d - кнопки, с соответствующим текстом

    l.AddWidget(a);
    l.AddWidget(b);
    l1.AddWidget(c);
    l1.AddWidget(d);

    l.AddLayout(l1);
    app.SetLayout(l); // app - основное приложение
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка точно в методе Aline и в способе добавления layot`а в layot. Подскажите, как это исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, например, в `Layout.AddLayout`.

Вы добавляете все виджеты из вложенного (в вашем примере — вертикального) лэйаута в родительский лэйаут (в вашем примере — горизонтальный). При этом следующий же вызов `Aline` (вы имели в виду `Align`?) внешнего лэйаута горизонтально перепозиционирует все контролы (что у вас и случается).

Я бы поменял дизайн вашего фреймворка следующим образом.

1. Лэйауты должны стать контейнерами, содержать свои элементы, а не отдавать их внешнему контейнеру.
2. Лэйауты должны быть частным случаем виджетов (хотя и невидимыми). Таким образом, виджет будет содержать коллекцию подвиджетов.

   - Виджет, являющийся лэйаутом, должен располагать свои подвиджеты.
   - Виджет, не являющийся лэйаутом, не должен содержать подвиджетов, а значит, не должен выставлять публичную функцию добавления подвиждета.
3. Координаты X и Y должны определяться лэйаутом, содержащим данный элемент, и таким образом не должны быть доступны на запись. (Вам стоит подумать, будут ли это абсолютные или относительные координаты.)

Comment: Спасибо. Layout не мог наследовать от Widget, потому, что виджет должен уметь реагировать на действия пользователя, а Layout - нет. Добавил спец. класс Object, содержащий информацию о месте и размерах, от него наследуют и Widget и Layout. Ф-цию Align оставил в том же виде, за исключением того, что в цикле идет проверка, не является ли объект layout`ом, и если да, то после настройки координат и размеров,  вызывается его Align. Пока, вроде, работает.